# Python youtube API oauth2client invalid_grant after a while

Tags: python, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I have a bot that uploads a Youtube video every 24 hours using the Youtube API. I have looked at the examples at https://github.com/SteBurz/youtube-uploader (which is just https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video rewritten in Python 3), but after a week or so, it gives me `invalid_grant` when I try to upload a video.

Here is the part of the code that "builds" the API. I tried using the `refresh` method but that didn't seem to be the answer.

```py
import http.client
import httplib2
import os
import random
import time

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

# References:
# https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video
# https://github.com/SteBurz/youtube-uploader

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = os.path.join(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    "..",
    "credentials-youtube.json"
)

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
]
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():
        credential_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'credentials.json')
        store = Storage(credential_path)
        credentials = store.get()
        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
                flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
                credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        else:
            credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
        return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 1):

The invalid_grant error is a catch all error for a lot of things.  Currently invalid_grant normally means that your refresh token has expired.

A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

The trick is to go to Google cloud console and set your project to production  then your refresh tokens will last longer then seven days

[image]

As for your code you need to get it to request a new access token as the one you have is no longer working. So delete what ever is in store